# create stored procedure with a 'use' statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i inherited an ms sql server 2008 server application and upon checking the stored procedures, i noticed that they start with a `USE [ELECS]` statement, **ELECS** being the database name.

when i tried to recreate one of the stored procedures, what i got was an error saying that a stored procedure cannot have a use statement.

> Msg 154, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TESTME, Line 3 a USE database
>   statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.

does ms sql server have a special feature that allows this?

Comment: Please post exactly what you have seen - we can't guess at what you saw. You can delete the irrelevant parts of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You most likely saw `USE` above the `CREATE`/`ALTER PROCEDURE` statement.

In which case it was being used to set which database the procedure should be updated on.

It cannot be used within a stored procedure, but if you wish to make reference to a different database you can set this in your table reference. Ie: for a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `Go` before `USE[databaseName]` statement. Worked for me in SQL 2005

Example:

```
GO

USE [Database_Name]

Go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure_name]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are certain "top level" statements that need to come first in an execution block.  You can cap off/close an execution block with the word `GO`

So:

```
USE [db]
GO

CREATE PROC....
```

If you're talking about a `USE` statement inside the sproc, then no, you can't do that.  The sproc is already scoped by the DB it was created in.  If you want to access another DB you need to use three-part naming, e.g. `ELECS.dbo.tablename` assuming `dbo` is your schema.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, the USE statement is not really part of the stored procedure but rather it's own statement that instructs the tool (i.e. Enterprise Manager or Query Analyzer) which database to use. It never gets send to the sql server itself and has no meaning for it...

Comment: This is not true. Easily demonstrated that it is not just a client tools feature by `EXEC ('USE tempdb;SELECT * FROM sys.objects' )` it is also listed as a [TSQL keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx). Perhaps you were thinking of `GO`

Comment: @Zdravko,  you could just as easily write `EXEC ('USE tempdb;SELECT * FROM [OtherDBName].sys.objects' )`.  All the Use statement does is tell the client tool what database to use when no database is explicitly mentioned in the sql statement.  All objects in SQL have 4 potential parts to their fully qualified name, and if you omit the beginning ones  the client tools fill in the missing ones with whatever the default is...